# A question on application of Schroder-Bernstein theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Could anyone give me some hints on how to use the Schroder-Bernstein Theorem to prove the following? Cause I am stuck at the question. Thank you.

We define a set B to be a non-empty subset of the closed interval [8,9].

Prove that the union [1,2] U [3,4] has the same cardinality with union [1,2] U B.

Comment: Schroder-Bernstein says we need an injection going each way. Which injection are you having difficulty finding?

Comment: First of all, i m not sure if i need to split into cases cause set B can be varies from 1 element to the elements of whole [8, 9]. And i had thought of both direction of injections, but the one from [1, 2] U [3, 4] to [1, 2] U B seems more difficult, cause there seems to be more elements in [1,2]U[3,4] than [1,2] U B. The injection from [1,2] U B to [1,2] U [3,4] is elements from [1,2 ] map to [1,2] and elements from B maps to elements in [3,4] ? But i m unsure how to write down the injection mappings explicitly, cause i m just beginner in real analysis. Thank you.

Comment: Think about it as follows. The elements of $B$ are numbers between 8 and 9. How do you take a number between 8 and 9 and map it to a number between 3 and 4. Think about how you could map the end points. For the other direction, think about how you could $[0,2]$ to $[0,1]$ invectively. How could you use that idea to map $[1,2] \cup [3,4]$ to $[1,2]$.

Comment: O, I had tried it out. For mapping from B to [3,4], I set the elements x in B to become (x-2)/2, so that all those elements will map to [3, 3.5]. Plus there is injection from [1,2] to [1,2] with the mapping f(x) = x.  For mapping from [1,2] U [3,4] to [1,2], I had set the elements y from [3,4] to become y/3 so to fit into [1, 4/3]; while I set the elements z from [1,2] to become (y+2)/2 so to fit into [1.5, 2]. And there will be no elements from [1,2] U [3,4] map to B. So will the above combined with Schroder-Bernstein Theorem shows that the size of [1,2] U [3,4] and [1,2] U B are the same?Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\in [1,2]\cup B$ let $f(x)=x$ if $x\in [1,2]$, or let $f(x)=x-5$ if $x\in B.$

For $y\in [1,2]\cup [3,4]$ let $g(y)=\frac {y+2}{3}.$

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution is elegant.

Comment: @RameshKarl . By a similar method, if $J$  is any real interval of non-$0$ length then $|J|=|\Bbb R|,$ and if $J\subset S\subset\Bbb R$ then $|S|=|\Bbb R$.

Comment: O, that's brilliant! Thank you so much!